# E-commerce - Does higher delivery time lead to lower sales?

Tags: regression, time-series, statistical-significance

#### Question

I have a practical problem and am seeking guidance on how to use statistical methods to solve it.

I have an online store. The products in the online store have varying availability:

- 24 hours if the product is in my warehouse
- 3 days otherwise

The availability of the product is shown to the customer before purchase. Based on historical sales and availability data, I need to determine **if customers are more likely to buy the product, if it is in my warehouse**. Even better, I'd like to have an estimate on percentage of sales that were lost because the customer decided not to purchase the product, due to higher delivery time.

Notes:

- Availability of a product changes in time. If I have 5 pieces on stock and somebody buys them on Monday, and new supplies arrive to my warehouse on Friday. From Monday to Friday, the customers see "3 days" as the delivery time 4 days.
- Products with higher sales are more likely to have lower delivery time. It is not always the case, but we cannot assume these two variables to be independent.
- I am afraid I don't have enough data to confidently evaluate the lost sales on any individual product. The calculation should be done over the whole dataset.

#### Data format

I'm adding examples of my data to clarify the question.

Warehouse intakes (indicates how much came to the warehouse):

| timestamp | product_id | amount_received |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2025-01-01 08:00:03 | 20 | 3 |
| 2025-01-01 08:00:03 | 30 | 5 |
| 2025-01-06 08:00:03 | 20 | 2 |
| 2025-01-06 08:00:03 | 40 | 4 |

Sales data (indicates how much left the warehouse):

| order_id | timestamp | product_id | amount_sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2025-01-01 13:24:45 | 10 | 3 |
| 1 | 2025-01-02 13:24:45 | 20 | 1 |
| 1 | 2025-01-02 13:24:45 | 30 | 1 |
| 2 | 2026-02-01 02:00:05 | 20 | 4 |
| 2 | 2026-02-01 02:00:05 | 40 | 5 |

We might calculate the amount of product in the warehouse at any given time as a sum of what was received minus sum of what was sold. The amount of product in the warehouse is displayed to the customer on the website. We are trying to determine if it impacts sales.

#### What I've tried

I've tried to figure out if this can be done using t-test, or linear regression, but wasn't able to formulate the problem in a way that would enable me to use either of these methods.

This is an updated version of the question, since the first version was unclear. If you are missing any information / something is unclear, pls let me know and I'll update the question.

Comment: Do have any visibility into how a product delivery time changes as it becomes more popular? For example, a new product might start out with a 3 day delivery. As you learn that it is a best seller, that might come down to 1 days. If you compare sales right around the change, demand will be roughly constant, but the delivery time will have some variation.

Comment: @dimitriy I have historical data on product delivery time, and on sales, but even best seller are sometimes out of local stock. As I only have few datapoints for each product, I think this requires a more robust approach than comparing availability and sales of a single product at a time.

Comment: Relevant pieces of information that may be needed to get a meaningful result out of such analysis: How many customers viewed the product (each day) & whether there were any promotions or not. Also product categories if your website sells products as different as say toys and furniture. Some products (eg. textbooks / school supplies) have seasonal demand & that could make a difference as well. Or you can make large assumptions that any difference you see in order rates are due to the shipping estimate; perhaps that's reasonable for your website.

Answer (score 1):

For each of your products compute the frequency of sales conditional on whether it was in the warehouse or not. For this you need to compute the time that the product has been in stock and the time that it has not been in stock and the number of sales during each of those time periods.

Potentially, if you have a lot of data, you could also compute this per hour of the day, or day of the week, if you have a lot of hourly variations in your availability of the product.

Then you have a list of products and frequencies like

```
Product ID    Sales in stock     Sales not in stock
              [amount per day]   [amount per day]
1             3                  2
2.            0.3                0.32
.. etc
```

I would plot these as a scatter plot to inspect visually whether there are deviations from a straight line.

You could add lines that indicate a p-value for deviating from the line (e.g. based on any procedure for an [AB testing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing)). But this is not so easy because both groups may not have been equally exposed, but for the lines you could assume the average exposure among all groups, or you divide the scatter plot into multiple groups depending on the relative exposure. In addition, you can compute for each point individually whether some boundary is passed and use colour or grayscale to plot to indicate those points.

The scatter plot might also be augmented with contour lines indicating the number of sales lost.

There are several interesting complex analysises that you can do. But this becomes very broad. An example, your orders have multiple products and you could analyse whether there are interactions. Possibly the availability of some key product increases the sales of other products?